# Issue with clicking vertically aligned Bar Buttons outside of the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to align two `UIBarButtonItem`s vertically on the right side of my `UINavigationBar`. I am using a custom view, and aligning two buttons within that.

Here is the code:

```
let rightBarButtonCustomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 90))
        
        let settingsButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "gearshape.fill"), for: .normal)
        settingsButton.backgroundColor = preferredBackgroundColor
        settingsButton.tintColor = .accentColor
    
        settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSettingsScreen), for: .touchUpInside)
        settingsButton.layer.cornerRadius = settingsButton.frame.size.height / 2
        settingsButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        settingsButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.label.cgColor
        settingsButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        rightBarButtonCustomView.addSubview(settingsButton)
        
        //NotificationButton
        let notificationsButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 40, height: 40))
        notificationsButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "bell.fill"), for: .normal)
        notificationsButton.backgroundColor = preferredBackgroundColor
        notificationsButton.tintColor = .accentColor

        notificationsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openNotificationScreen), for: .touchUpInside)
        notificationsButton.layer.cornerRadius = notificationsButton.frame.size.height / 2
        notificationsButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        notificationsButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.label.cgColor
        notificationsButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        rightBarButtonCustomView.addSubview(notificationsButton)
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButtonCustomView)
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Image1]

Pretty good right?

Well, the issue is that the notification button is not receiving clicks, but the settings button is. My guess is that the notification button is outside of the navigation bar, as shown in this picture (`UINavigationBar` is blue, my `rightBarButtonCustomView` is red):
[image: Image2]

I have tried to use constraints, increase the height of the navigation bar, but nothing seemed to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Based on your images, it does not appear that you are in a Navigation Controller stack? If that's the case, you'd be much better off **not** using a `UINavigationBar`. If you **are** in a Navigation Controller stack (that is, you get to this viewController by "pushing" it), show the code you're using to setup the navigation bar appearance.

Answer (score -1):

The below code is working well for me.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
}
```

[image]

Comment: The height is right for less than a second, then immediately goes back to normal. Should I maybe do a different view function? (ie. viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear())

Comment: Hi @goatofanerd You are testing it on a real device or on a simulator??

Comment: Real device! Would that matter?

Comment: Yes, it is. Device OS matter too. Kindly check it on your simulator.

Comment: Same result sadly :( I can attach a video of the result if you wish. Let me try to put your code in a different view function

Comment: Ok, found something, I set the `largeTitleDisplayMode` of the navigation bar to `.always`. And the `prefersLargeTitle` to `true`. The blueness of the navigation bar now extends past the notification button, still no clickability though :(

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rTkAB-QTqHpA96lS-q8fWr-l08aVSF7P/view?usp=sharing

You can check the above test project in which you can increase the navigation bar area. I will test the button click thing tomorrow.
Thanks

Comment: @goatofanerd did you get a chance to try the above code?